# CNContactPickerViewController shows up even after disabling access from settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, cncontact

I am displaying a `CNContactPickerViewController`. Suppose if I disable the access from settings, it should not allow to open the controller or should say pop up saying Contacts access is disabled. But in turn it is opening the view. Why is it so ? Anyone have idea about it. Is it framework bug, or should I should forcefully check using `CNContactStore requestAccessForEntityType:` method?

```
self.mContactBookController = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
mContactBookController.displayedPropertyKeys = @[CNContactEmailAddressesKey];
mContactBookController.predicateForEnablingContact = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"emailAddresses.@count > 0"];
[app.window.rootViewController presentViewController:mContactBookController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactPickerViewController_Class/):

> The app using contact picker view does not need access to the user’s
>   contacts and the user will not be prompted for “grant permission”
>   access. The app has access only to the user’s final selection.

So, no, it's not a bug and you don't need to check.